# Multiple prefixes in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

so I'm using my bot on mobile a bit and so are the users, but the problem is most people's autocorrect turn it into Pb instead of pb - which is the prefix, how do you make it so I can have `pb` and `Pb` as my prefixes?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this?

Comment: It's cause the post got taken down because it wasn't specific enough

Comment: Yeah, but if you repost the same question word for word, it's going to have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

My solution would be using `.toLowerCase()` to put the user input in a lowercase condition. So for example (Note that this is a raw example and may varies with your code):

```
client.on("message", message => {
    const BotPrefix = "pb";
    
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(BotPrefix))
    {
        // Do you stuff.
    }
});
```

Now users can use prefixes in all kinds of forms: `PB`, `pb`, `pB`, `Pb` because the message will be in lowercase. Make sure your prefix is also in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

the solution above works  for what you're trying to do but if you wanna have multiple prefixes you can use

```
const prefix = message.content.includes("prefix") ? "prefix" : "another prefix"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. This works for multiple prefixes and its an easy fix.
You can make as many prefixes as you want with it.

`const prefixes = ('pb', 'Pb');`

Answer (score 0):

If this still not completely answered. Try this code because it works for me.

```
    const prefix = require('./config.json'); //when you are using .json
    
           client.on('message' msg => {
                 if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}text`){ 
              
             //some code 
        
        } 
        })
```

Inside of your .json

```
    {
      "prefix" : "pb",
      "token" : "your-token-here"
    }
```

This is v13 of discord.js